# Editing ephemeral messages in discord jda

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am sending an ephemeral message with an EntitySelectMenu. When the user selects the items in this menu, I need to change the content of the ephemeral message to some text like "abc".
I tried doing it like this:

In EntitySelectInterection

```
event.deferEdit().queue(); // defer editing to make sure menu is disabled
event.getHook().retrieveOriginal().queue(message -> { // get original message
    String content = "abc";
    message.editMessage(content).queue(); // update message content
});
```

But this edits the text of the message to which the ephemeral is attached, but not the ephemeral itself.
Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit messages using `getHook()`. For instance:

```java
event.deferEdit().queue();
event.getHook().editOriginal("abc").queue();
```

Using the message instead, will use a bot endpoint rather than an interaction endpoint.